# Table looks wrong in Chrome, after refreshing everything is ok

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, row

I've got problem with the table. On Firefox it looks great, but when I'm opening it on Chrome for first time table is in different position. Refresh repairs everything. What I did wrong?

CSS

```
    #spec0{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 566px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    #spec1{
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    width: 566px;
    height: 20px;
    }

    #table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 566px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-top: 11px;
    position: static;
    }

    #tr{
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    height: 10px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    text-align: right;
    }


    #tr1{
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    height: 10px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    }

    #tr3{
    height: 10px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: left;
    }
```

HTML

```
<table id="table">
  <tr id="spec">
    <th id="tr">Template</th>
    <th id="tr3">Template</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="spec1">
    <td id="tr">Template</td>
    <td id="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="spec">
    <td id="tr">Template</td>
    <td id="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="spec1">
    <td id="tr">Template</td>
    <td id="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="spec">
    <td id="tr">Template</td>
    <td id="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="spec1">
    <td id="tr">Template</td>
    <td id="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="spec">
    <td id="tr">Template</td>
    <td id="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="spec1">
    <td id="tr">Template</td>
    <td id="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="spec">
    <td id="tr">Template</td>
    <td id="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="spec1">
    <td id="tr">Template</td>
    <td id="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="spec">
    <td id="tr">Template</td>
    <td id="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="spec1">
    <td id="tr"></td>
    <td id="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image; first launch from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9ZmM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using mutiple equal ID's , ID's must be unique , so change to class, and you were trying to apply `#spec0` when you had only `id="spec"`

```css
.spec {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 566px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.spec1 {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  width: 566px;
  height: 20px;
}
#table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 566px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: 11px;
  position: static;
}
.tr {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 10px;
  font-size: 11pt;
  text-align: right;
}
.tr1 {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 10px;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

.tr3 {
  height: 10px;
  font-size: 11pt;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr class="spec">
    <th class="tr">Template</th>
    <th class="tr3">Template</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="spec1">
    <td class="tr">Template</td>
    <td class="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="spec">
    <td class="tr">Template</td>
    <td class="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="spec1">
    <td class="tr">Template</td>
    <td class="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="spec">
    <td class="tr">Template</td>
    <td class="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="spec1">
    <td class="tr">Template</td>
    <td class="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="spec">
    <td class="tr">Template</td>
    <td class="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="spec1">
    <td class="tr">Template</td>
    <td class="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="spec">
    <td class="tr">Template</td>
    <td class="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="spec1">
    <td class="tr">Template</td>
    <td class="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="spec">
    <td class="tr">Template</td>
    <td class="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="spec1">
    <td class="tr"></td>
    <td class="tr1">Template</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It works fine, but still table is in wrong position, F5 or ctrl+scroll helps. It only happens on chrome. What I did wrong?

Comment: #table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 566px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
margin-top: 11px;
margin-left:370px;
position: absolute;
}

It works for me, thank you!